# What are some of the current relevant fully homomorphic schemes?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

As of February 2017, I have the feeling that all information on FHE is currently a bit scattered and finding a good summary/ timeline on the topic is really hard.

I'm currently looking into FHE over standard/ ring-LWE which seems to have one of the better security assumptions. Are there any other relevant schemes/ methods that are very refined or even practically in use?

Comment: You can always get a decent idea of the latest results in an area by going to http://eprint.iacr.org/complete/ and looking for your topic, like "FHE". So I'm not sure what you mean by "scattered". Most of these papers also mention/explain previous work on the topic, so the timeline is not that hard to construct.

Comment: As for your specific question: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/065 says that the only real current alternative to lattice-baaed FHE is FHE over the integers, building on the AGCD assumption.